# How to copy a member in an object in one container to another container using an algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have a container of objects and I would like to copy the same member from each object to a container of that member's type.

I.e.  Something like this:

```
struct X { int x; }

std::vector<X> src;
std::vector<int> dst;

...

auto it_dst = dst.begin();
for (auto& element : src) {
  *(it_dst++) = element.x;
}
```

Of course, using an algorithm and not a for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a job for `transform` with a lambda (I consider you haven't allocated your vector):

```
std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(dst),
               [](const auto& v) -> int { return v.x; });
```

Comment: About allocating my vector.  Yeah, I did, just didn't show it.  It's in the `...`. ;)

Comment: OK, in that case, no need for the back_inserter, just do `dst.begin()`.

Comment: Any reason not to deduce the return-type?

Comment: @Deduplicator not really. I think it's good to show the syntax from time to time, I know I'm not yet accustomed to it.